# Performance Quetions. Search database with range query or with and id

Tags: performance, query-performance, sqlite

I have a database, consisting of the following columns

- `id`, a string looking like this `8b28347448d3fff` (15 length)
- `x`, a decimal (8,6)
- `y`, a decimal (9,6)

All the columns have Indexes on them. Now, I wan to find matching pairs. On the table side `foo`, there can be up to 300k of rows. There are two ways to query the table I can think of. First, this one:

Using a `WHERE ... IN`. On the query side, there might be up to 11k elements in `possible_matching_indexes`.

```
SELECT id FROM foo WHERE id IN (possible_matching_indexes);
```

Another one would be this, which would only result in four values (`x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2`) on the query side

```
SELECT id FROM foo WHERE (x BETWEEN x1 and x2) AND (x BETWEEN y1 and y2);
```

Which one is more likely to more performant? I am using a SQLite database. But I guess this can be estimated from any SQL based database?

Comment: I don't mean to be smart, but why don't you test this on your own system (hardware, tables and rdbms)? Your quote `But I guess this can be estimated from any SQL based database?` does **not** hold generally **at all**. Various systems use different types of [BTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) and there are various balancing algorithms. Add to that differences in optimiser code and different systems will have different thresholds for choosing different joining algorithms... Quite frankly, *hic sunt leones!*

Comment: @Vérace thanks for your hint! I am by no means a database expert, just starting diving into it and basically everything you wrote after 'at all' is new to me. I thought by coming here and asking this question I might get some more insights into this whole topic.

Comment: Be prepared to do lots of searching and reading of technical blogs/papers - it's a geek's paradise! :-)

Comment: @Vérace Thats why I like it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IN` clause generally is known to be able to cause cardinality estimation issues under certain circumstances (typically with larger lists of items) among multiple database systems. I can't speak for SQLite specifically, but 11k is a lot of items to stuff in one `IN` clause regardless. The `IN` clause is logically similar to a bunch of `OR`s.

If those were your only two options I'd vote for the range filter. But there's a third option that I prefer best. Since you seem to know the `id`s already of the 11k items you want, you should put them in a temporary table, and then join that table to your actual table, `foo`, by the `id` field. This is a more relational approach that generally works better over large lists in an `IN` clause.

Of course, any of the solutions mentioned are dependent on your table `foo` being properly indexed. And like Verace mentioned, the best way to find out is to just test, as there's a lot of granular factors that can affect performance. The aforementioned advice is just general guidance.

Comment: I like the idea of `JOIN`. I have to check if that is feasable on a mobile device. thanks!

Comment: @four-eyes `JOIN`s are totally allowed, syntactically valid, and just fine performance-wise in SQLite on a mobile device. I do them regularly. (Again, assuming you're tables are indexed properly.)

Comment: Yes, I know that. But the data in the `IN` clause comes from a MapView, which means the user pans, drags and zooms around quickly... Thus with every MapView change I need to delete the old data from the table, insert the new data into the table, (calcualte the index?) and then perform the `JOIN`.

Comment: @four-eyes Not sure I fully follow. Everytime you'd have to create a temp table of `id`s to run the query is the same amount of times you would've had to generate the `IN` clause query and run it. If it were me, creating the temp table and running the `JOIN` query would be part of the same query batch. Creating a **temp** table is a trivial thing.

Comment: You understand it right. I was just thinking loudly, being not sure if `DELETING` prev. entries from the table, `INSERTING` new ones, creating the `INDEX` and the performing a `JOIN` would be faster than generating the `IN` clause query (or overcoming the performance issues of the `IN` clause query)

Comment: It'll be faster than **running** the `IN` clause the same number of times (whenever the MapView changed). But instead of deleting / inserting `id`s from the temp table multiple times, I'd just create a new temp table with the new list of `id`s each time (and let the old one get garbage collected). And again, I'd only generate the query to create the temp table but not run it each time they move in the MapView. I'd only execute the SQL right before they actually need the data for the current view they settle in, in the MapView.